# I can't directly download previous versions of a file from Dropbox anymore?

Tags: dropbox

Previously I could directly download a previous version of the file. However, since from I don't know when (it was still fine less than a month ago), there seems to be no longer the "download" option when I click on a previous version of a file. Instead, the button "Show in File Browser" replaced it, if the file is still on my system.

This isn't helpful at all, since the version in my File Explorer of course is the newest version, and there is no way to get the previous versions directly from there. The only other option seems to be "Restore", which I really don't want to do since it will just overwrite the newest version directly. As a programmer, I obviously will want to compare the current version with a previous version, instead of directly overwriting.

Is there any way to still download the previous version of a file, even if the the newest version of this file is on my File System?

EDIT: Screenshot here [image: screenshot]

Comment: Is the type of file significant? Although is this happening to all files? Can you provide a screenshot? Just to make sure we're looking at the same thing.

Comment: @w3dk I added the screenshot. I don't think it's relevant to the file type. The "Download" button is just simply replaced.

Comment: @w3dk I feel like this is a change done wrong on the part of Dropbox. It makes sense to locate a current file in your system, but somehow the previous versions interface now has this button as well.

Comment: Hhmm, weird. Yesterday I had the "Download" button when viewing previous versions of the file. But today I don't. But I don't see the "Show in File Browser" button either. In the list of "previous versions" (which looks different to yesterday) I see just a "Restore" and "Cancel" button at the end of the list. The navigation is also missing on the left. However, clicking the filename downloads the file instead of previewing it - as it did yesterday. I'm unable to "preview" a previous version, as I could before. (However, text files appear to open directly in the browser, but can then be saved.)

Comment: This "change" is certainly a step backwards IMO. However, this seems to be a different "change" to what you are seeing?! What "type" of account do you have? Free, Pro, Business?

Comment: @w3dk Funny I also see this change today. Maybe they heard my and other users' complaints in the user forums and made the change, or maybe they're testing different UI changes all the time. In any case I don't think it's wise for them to roll out such big changes on the production version of their app so rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible by clicking on the previous file in the list (Preview) and when the preview url loads there is a download button at the top of the page.